# what is (.:format) appended to url path during rake routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I run `rake routes`, I get something like this:

```
signin        /signin(.:format)                            application#signin
```

What is the **(.:format)** in the middle?

Answer (score 3):

It's an optional format. It matches URLs like:

```
/signin
/signin.html
/signin.json
```

This format can then be used in the controller. For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render xml: @users}
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
  end
end
```

This code snippet is from [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html). See more details in the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).